# Render raw image from response

Tags: bixby

Is there a way to render image we get from the response?
My response looks like this:

```
var rawResponse = "�PNG...."; // truncated for example
```

I saw in all examples that image is rendered through URL only, either from local assets or external URL.

When I saw that it doesn't work when I just put it into my view, I also tried converting it to base64 but still it doesn't render. This is what I used:

```
var base64 = require("base64");
var rawResponse = "�PNG....";
var base64Response = base64.encode(rawResponse);
return 'data:image/png;base64,'+b64Response;
```

Is there a way to render image not using local files or external URL?

---

EDIT

So here's how code looks like

```
var base64 = require("base64");

module.exports.function = function getImage (query) {

  const result = {}
  const image =  http.getUrl("https://via.placeholder.com/150/f66b97"); 
  result.image = toBase64(image);
  
  return result;
}

const toBase64 = (img) => {
  var b64Response = base64.encode(img);
  let src = 'data:image/png;base64,'+b64Response;
  return src;
}

 
structure (ImageResult) {
  description (Image Result)
  property (image) {
    type (Image)
    min (Optional) max (One)
  }
}


structure (Image){
  property (image) {
    type (core.BaseImage)
    min (Optional) max (One)
    visibility (Default)
  }
}

layout {
  match: ImageResult (this)
  mode (Details)
  content {
    section {
      content {
        divider 
        image {
          url{
            template ("#{value (this.image)}")
          }
        } 
        divider
        } 
      
    }
  }
}
```

In this code i just simplified the usage. This still works when i provide URL, local or external, or provide some image in base64 format.

Either the response is bad or the conversion is not done well... However when i try to convert it into base64 as a result i get broken image.

I'm i doing something wrong?

Comment: It would be good to see the code for the Action behind this javascript and the Concept that is being returned by the Action

Comment: @BixbyDevSupportOne i updated the question and now you can see the code

Answer (score 1):

I've confirmed that this works. I would recommend checking the image data being returned to make sure the correct information is being encoded and returned.

Additionally, you will also need to define the `image` key in your result view where the `url` is your encoded return string.

Comment: Yeah correct base64 works, but something gets wrong when i get byte array as a response. I updated the question so you can see

Comment: Thanks for the additional information! I'm currently investigating further but I'll be sure to update my answer once I know more.